# Помогите чайнику понять пример из функицонального программирования

Tags: python, функции, функциональное-программирование

Уважаемое сообщество, вынужден обратиться к вам за помощью, прошу не судить строго, изучаю Python. В начале раздела по ООП, есть небольшая глава про функциональное программирование. Как всегда, весь код который подается набираю в PyCharm. Вот собственно что меня заинтересовало:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С первой функцией мне все понятно. А вот при попытке вывести функцию со второго примера:

```
def increment(a):
    return a + 1

increment(a)
```

получаю сообщение с ошибкой что переменная а не определена. В связи с этим **первый вопрос**: где определять переменную, если по определению в функциональном программировании функция не пологается на данные за ее пределами и не изменяет их? А в этом примере я не вижу что бы данные определялись внутри функции.

**Второй вопрос** возник после изучения и тестирования все той же функции:

почему данный код:

```
def increment(a):
    return a + 1
    print(a)

increment(1)
```

ничего не выводит(даже ошибки), у нас же есть инструкция print...

а код:

```
def increment(a):
    return a + 1

print(increment(1))
```

выведет значение (что вообщем-то верно).

Comment: `a` нигде не определена, поэтому ошибка; не выводит, потому что перед этим `return`; https://www.python.org/doc/

Comment: ознакомьтесь в гугле с любой статьёй 'область видимости в python' . эта неявная штука обычно обходится в учебниках и вызывает много ошибок.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def increment(a):
    return a + 1

increment(a)
```

вы вызываете метод в глобальном окружении в котором не определенна переменная "a" и при этом вы пытаетесь ее передать, определите ее до вызова метода

```
def increment(a):
    return a + 1
    print(a)

increment(1)
```

return вызывает выход из метода, поэтому функция print не вызывается

```
def increment(a):
    return a + 1

print(increment(1))
```

все верно потому что вы возвращаете результат функции из метода в метод Print

UPD для первого вариант вот так можно определить переменную

```
a = 7
def increment(a):
    return a + 1
increment(a)
```

или вот так

```
def increment(a):
    return a + 1
a = 7
increment(a)
```

главное чтобы она была в той же области видимости и до вызова функции

Comment: Спасибо, Дмитрий! Уточните, определить переменную до вызова метода именно в функции или в любом месте между функцией и ее вызовом?

Comment: я дополнил пост, посмотрите UPD, главная идея чтобы области видимости были одинаковые и определение было до вызова функции ;)

Answer (score 4):

> где определять переменную

Именно переменную, в том смысле, который вкладывают в это слово императивные языки – желательно нигде.

В терминах функционального программирования, переменная это имя, которое может быть связано с произвольным значением, но не может быть переназначено в рамках одного вычисления. Т.е. имеется в виду переменная величина в математическом смысле.

```
t = 3x
```

это типичное действие в математике, а

```
x = x + 1
```

нонсенс, так как

```
x - x = 1
0 = 1
```

А функциональное программирование построено на математических законах.

В python нет явного механизма, запрещающего переопределение переменных, это на совести программиста. Если он не переназначает переменные и не меняет их содержимое иным способом, то это никак не противоречат принципами функционального программирования, и такие переменные нужны и даже необходимы.

> по определению в функциональном программировании функция не полагается на данные за ее пределами и не изменяет их

Чистая функция не полагается на внешние *изменяемые* данные и не изменяет их сама, это так. Но никто не мешает ей обращаться к внешним *неизменяемым* данным, например:

```
def circumference(r):
    return 2 * math.pi * r
```

Эта функция чистая, опять же с оговоркой, если кто-нибудь захочет переназначить значение `math.pi`, язык этому никак не воспрепятствует, он подразумевает, что пользователю хватит здравомыслия не делать этого.

И даже в следующем примере обе функции `f` и `g` – чистые

```
def f(x):
    def g(y):
        return 2 * x + 3 * y

    return g(1) * g(2)
```

Хотя `g` и полагается на внешний параметр `x`, в рамках вычисления значения `f(x)` он неизменен, и `g` для разных значений `x` это разные функции, а не одна и та же функция, дающая разные результаты.

Answer (score 2):

Вот так определить переменную:

```
def increment(a):
    return a + 1
a = 1
print(f"До использования функции а={a}")
a = increment(a)
print(f"После использования функции а={a}")
```

А здесь у вас ошибка:

```
def increment(a):
    return a + 1
    print(a)
```

Нужно `print(a)` поставить над `return` - поскольку по сути это команда завершает выполнение функции и функция print уже не выполняется (из-за отступов, которые заменяют форматирование скобками в других языках):

```
def increment(a):
    result = a + 1            
    print(result)
    return result
```

---

**UPD.** У вас на листинге из книги в вопросе, кстати, в первом случае объявлена переменная `а=0` до функции, и передается она в функцию не через аргументы, а через `global`, а во втором случае уже как аргумент.

Comment: Что-то про отступы и синтаксическую ошибку странное, в первом примере как раз синтаксическая ошибка есть

Comment: Спасибо за пояснения! Насколько я понял из комментария к вашему ответу, видимо из-за редактора сайта не отобразился отступ в строке в которой идет определение переменной. Т.е. в функциональном программировании переменные определяются только внутри функций?

Comment: @VartaFather, нет, это я в попыхах написал не совсем верно ))) Исправил. Наоборот, переменные объявленные в теле функции не будут видны вне тела функции, а глобальные переменные видны во всем скрипте

Comment: `print(f"До использования функции а={a}"` <- синтаксическая ошибка; *"А здесь у вас синтаксическая ошибка:"* <- нет синтаксической ошибки

Comment: @VartaFather причём тут функциональное программирование? https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Функциональное_программирование

Comment: @dIm0n Про синтаксис не верно написал, исправил. А по отступам - если бы перед принтом их не было, то человек бы увидел ошибку, что `name 'a' is not defined`

Comment: А вы свой код проверяете? ``а`` что до, что после равно 1.

Comment: @Эникейщик Нет, не проверял ))) Исправил, спасибо за замечание

Answer (score 2):

По второму вопросу:

Переменную можно нигде не определять.

Если в языке есть поддержка хвостовой рекурсии (в python в коробке нет), то будет работать такой динамичный мир:

```
def world_iteration(a,b):
  will_a = increment(a)
  will_b = increment(b)
  world_iteration(will_a,will_b)

world_iteration(0,0)
```